# How can I put items of different sizes in one page avoiding too many gaps between them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a set of rectangles of different sizes and I want to put them next to each other so there are as little gaps in there as possible:
[image]

but for:

```
<div class="box" >
    <div class="item item-001" ></div>
    <div class="item item-003" ></div>
    <div class="item item-005" ></div>
    <div class="item item-002" ></div>
    <div class="item item-004" ></div>
    <div class="item item-001" ></div>
    <div class="item item-001" ></div>
    <div class="item item-003" ></div>
    <div class="item item-004" ></div>
    <div class="item item-001" ></div>
</div>
```

and

```
div.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding: 3px;
}

div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 100px;
}
div.item-001 {
    height: 100px;
}
div.item-002 {
    height: 150px;
}
div.item-003 {
    height: 50px;
}
div.item-004 {
    height: 250px;
}
div.item-005 {
    height: 350px;
}
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Is there a way I could achieve that result with plain css? I want to avoid css3 and javascript and I want the result to run on older browsers. If that is not possible, then I'd like to know if it is possible with css3 and if not, then I guess I'll try javascript.

link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hamidsafdari/aa10xzzt/1/

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/aa10xzzt/2/

Comment: FWIW, If you do end up having to use Javascript, the Isotope library does this. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ . Example: http://www.mymoroccanguide.com/en-GB/Gallery

Comment: In my humble opinion, I think there will have to be "some" javascript involved in this unfortunately.

Comment: You can use jquery Masonry grid layout for this
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery and you don't want to do all by yourself when someone has already you can have a look at this plugin that may help you: [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/masonry)

This plugin builds a page layout like the one you are looking for.
**I that you asked to avoid JavaScript** know but this way you will be sure that you have a fallback for older browsers.

Comment: I guess you're right. Looked up and tried bunch of those libraries including Masonry but the problem with them is that they set the position of the element to absolute and the items inside the container sometimes bleed out of it. Found out that I could also use the column-count css3 property but each browser has a different version of it. Ended up setting a minimum height for the items inside the container so even though there is  a gap between elements, there is a little grid like symmetry there. Will do my own thing when I got enough time!

Answer (score 1):

As the items are of same width, you could use a multi-column layout and place the elements one below the other.

```
div.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding: 3px;
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
}
```

You might need to change the column count though.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aa0tfjLL/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply `font-size:0` to the parent elements and remove the `margin` from the child elements.

```
div.box {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
border: 1px solid #EEE;
padding: 3px;
font-size:0;        
}

div.item {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aa10xzzt/2/)

Comment: I assume this is not what's this user looking for.

Comment: Yes, I think the OP wanted the first image, not the second

Answer (score 0):

```
div.vertical{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px;
}
div.full{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa10xzzt/3/)

Please try above fiddle